# Printing prime numbers up to a user's input

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am making a quick program that will ask the user for a number and then output all the prime numbers up to that number:

```
n=int(input("Enter a number: "))
a=2
if n<=1:
    n=int(input("Enter another number: "))
while a<n:
    for i in range(2,n):
        if a%i==0:
            break
        else:
            print (a)
            break
    a=a+1
```

The problem I am having is that it won't print out `2`. For example, if I use `20` as my `n` value, it will print:

```
Enter a number: 20
3
5
7
9
11
13
15
17
19
```

Comment: You have other problems, 9 and 15 are not prime.

Comment: In your `for` loop you are using `break` for both `if` and `else`, means your `for` loop will execute only once (`for i=2`). In short you are checking divisiblity by `2` which will not be statisfied by odd numbers. That is why you are getting all odd numbers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have two mistakes:

1. The `else` is incorrectly indented, so it sits with the `if` not the `for` (you want to `print` if *all* values below `a` aren't factors of `a`, not on the first one that isn't); and
2. Your inner `range` goes up to `n`, not `a` (so always includes `a`, and `a % a == 0`).

This will work:

```
for a in range(2, n):
    for i in range(2, a):
        if a % i == 0:
            break
    else:
        print(a)
```

Note I have used a `for` loop to replace the outer `while`, which is generally better when you already know where to stop. You can make the code more efficient by checking up to the square root of `a`, and leaving out even numbers other than `2`, but I will leave those optimisations to you.

Answer (score 0):

You can start the loop from 1.

Your loop will start from 1, hence you will get 2 in output.